# Samsung S7 hacked and running some FTP server?

Tags: security

I believe my Samsung S7 was hacked. It looks like an external server with Linux is running via my router's FTP server ([Fritz!Box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fritz!box)):

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshots (click images to enlarge)</sup>

The second screenshot is from the system protocol, the third from a detection app I had downloaded.

Please help!

Comment: Dialog translation via Google Translate = "This allows the application to retrieve the internal system status. Shark software can then retrieve a variety of private and secure information, which you should never normally need." This seems like a normal warning from the device manufacturer to a person seeking root access. You probably haven't been hacked, but it is likely warning you that it is easier if you continue to do this. Also: "Diese Seite ist Englisch-dominant. Bitte übersetze deine Beiträge für die beste Hilfe."

Comment: I don't know where the Fritz!Box comes into play here and what makes you think of an FTP server running on your device. It might help if you describe how you obtained the screenshot. What app is it showing the details of? (PS: Diese Site benutzt Englisch für die Kommunikation. Ich habe Deine Frage daher übersetzt). // @wbogacz what makes you think about root access? I've removed that tag as it seems misleading. To me that rather looks like details on some permission, though I'm at a loss which one that should be. Oh: and your "shark software" is "malware" :)

Comment: @Izzy - I was just translating. If you had gotten here first, it would have come naturally; I used Google translate. And, it just sounded close to a root warning, where device makers try to "scare" the uninformed away.

Comment: @wbogacz I wasn't throwing blames, just wondering ;) Thanks for explaining! Besides: I was right with my assumption. The corresponding permission is [`DUMP`](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms#DUMP): "Allows an application to retrieve state dump information from system services. […] Evil apps could theoretically use this to access private and protected data."

Comment: Sorry, nicole – but the relation between your question and the screenshots is still unclear. The first screenshot is about app details (as I already explained in my answer), the second is the Chrome console while trying to download the Windows-10 ISO (why would one do such thing, especially on an Android device?) and the third is showing some file explorer details (oops: "Kitkat hack"? that's strange indeed). Without some more explanation, we're unable to help. As I already wrote, you need to give some context to what the screenshots stand for and what steps lead to those places.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. My phone sends all my Dates like Pictures ans Database to the other devices  (pc.laptop etc) through the fritz Box to the other server. The screenshots show THAT someone is making some stuff. And i want to know what i have to do to see clear whats going on on all devices. I had technical Support here at home.they said deleted all devices Buy new Handy. Pc.etc.and Search all jpg with Virus scan.but i cant Buy. So, sorry i cant better explain without writing a book. I understand u cant do. Thank you for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(Note: at the time this answer was written, only the first screenshot was present in the question post.)</sup>

Your screenshot shows details of some app you've selected. More specifically: it shows the permissions that app requested, as seen in the background. Obviously you've tapped one permission, so an explanation for that permission is shown. That permission is [DUMP](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms#DUMP).

This permission is normally used during development, to retrieve detailed debugging information to narrow down errors – which is why it has the [protection level](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms#protlevel) "development" assigned. For such a permission to become effective, the ROM must be signed with a development key – a case a normal user with a "normal device" shouldn't encounter.

To answer your direct question: No, this is not a sign of being "hacked". Just a sign a (careless) developer forgot to clean up :)

Comment: You speak German in addition to English, huh? But I guess not the majority of the users and visitors here :(

Comment: Hi.many thanks for the answers. Where can I beat everything? If I explained everything, it would be a 10 page text. I can do that gradually. I must first know if someone trusts this. 4 years ago I had a private stalker problem. It is definitely a known person. I have had the problem checked more expertly, but I can not afford the comprehensive "maneuver" to get around this problem (4kids). It is so that it shows me on all devices showing each device

Comment: @iBug the other way around. German is my native tongue ;) // Oh, I see what you mean. It's no "additional information", just a short summary intended for the case nicole could not understand English. As she can, I will remove this.

Comment: Connected to the network in the background are photos, voice recordings and so on. It can not be brought to the display because I'm not sure. For a short time can also be a misrepresentation festhalten.google accounts, etc. are not under my admin rights. So long story short: The Fritzbox is coupled via FTP access to an external Linux server. Whatsapp email fb etc not sure anymore .playstore not synonymous. Have tried to install it with apk s but after 2 days at the latest locks it

Comment: Me everything.I am an absolute layman. It may be more difficult to explain. I did a lot of screenshots, but I can not completely tell what's wrong ... the mask is ... and especially how can I solve this problem. Here I am not in the field I'm sorry. Then please just delete it. The DPA is not private either.

Comment: @nicole first, it would help to let us know which app you investigated (as I already suggested in my comments on the question). You are clearly viewing some app's details. So to give closer details, we'd need to know at least that.

Comment: Na ich hab so ziemlich alle untersucht .der screenshot ist etwas älter

Comment: @nicole Du solltest die Details in Deiner Frage ergänzen (und ja, einen aktuellen Screenshot auch – mit Erklärung, wie Du auf die entsprechende "Seite" gekommen bist). Die Kommentare hier sind nicht für eine Diskussion gedacht; leider benötigst Du allerdings ein wenig mehr "Reputation" (Punkte), um einen Chat-Raum nutzen zu können – was ich Dir sonst nahegelegt hätte. // Und gleich bekommen wir beide Ärger, weil wir "ausländisch kommunizieren" ;)